# select numbers from database for sum

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to get numbers from a database and use them in a sum. i don't really know how to start but i gave it go. i got an error when i echo just one number straight from the database which didn't help my self-a-steam. i don't know what i got wrong but i think it's a simple one. this is the code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$connection = mysql_connect("mysql15.000webhost.com", "a4987634_quiz", "**********")
or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("a4987634_quiz", $connection)
or die (mysql_error());

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];

$q1 = mysql_query ("SELECT 'q1' FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$q2 = mysql_query ("SELECT 'q2' FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$q3 = mysql_query ("SELECT 'q3' FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$q4 = mysql_query ("SELECT 'q4' FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$q5 = mysql_query ("SELECT 'q5' FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

$result = $q1 + $q2 + $q3 + $q4 + $q5 ;

echo $result ;

?>
```

thanks.

Comment: Also check what `mysql_query` actually returns. You can not use the `+` operator with it. The manual is your friend: http://php.net/mysql_query. It's not helpful if you ask a question without providing the exact error description btw.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: While you're on the manual pages, to which hakre provided a link, notice that use of `mysql_*` extension is highly discouraged, switch to PDO or `mysqli_*` instead

Comment: the error code is Resource id#9

Comment: It's not an error, you just don't know what are you doing. Please learn some basics about how to fetch data from from mysql in php before asking questions

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there is only one row in users for each username then:

```
Select q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 as total from users where username = '$username'
```

If there are more than one then you maybe want

```
Select Sum(q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5) as total from users where username = '$username'
```

Comment: +1 `+` to add columns, `sum` to add rows

Comment: i get an error. Resource id#9

Comment: I don't know php, but http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php makes it pretty obvious how to use the result of mysql_query, as well as telling you not to use mysql_ functions for new code...

Comment: No need to use curly brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use simple operators  here -

```
SELECT (q1+q2+q3+q4+q5) AS total FROM users WHERE username='$username'
```

Comment: It seems OP's current issue is summing of resultsets but not actural row field values.

Comment: -1 But `sum` takes only one parameter.  This gives a syntax error.

Comment: i got an error when i tried this

Comment: It would help if we knew what the error is....

Comment: You simply haven't fetched the results from the query. You'll have to execute a `mysql_fetch_assoc()` on the object returned from the `mysql_query()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add up resultsets directly but the specific field values read from each of them.
Add the field values read from each of the result set to sum up and then echo the result.

**Example**:

```
$result = 0;
$resultSetsArray = array( $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5 );  

foreach( $resultSetsArray as $rs ) {  
  while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $rs ) ) {  
    $result = $result + $row[ 1 ];  
    break; // while  
  } // while rs  
} // for each  

echo "result : " . $result;
```

---

You have better ways of summing of column values of a database table column.
It seems you need more learning and practice both in PHP and MySQL.