# Unable to get data from a database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i would like to get 5 peices of data from a database. the database looks like this...

id username password q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 hscore lscore

q1 stands for question one. hscore and lscore stand for high/last score.

the values for q1 q2 q3 q4 and q5 are all either 5, -1 or 0. if 5, this means they got the question correct, if -1 this means they got the question wrong and if 0 this means they haven't attempted that question yet.

i would like to get all of the values from all of the questions and add them together. this will then give me a last score value which i can print on the screen and update the database whith.

this is my attempt and it doesn't seem to work. if anyone knows why or has a solution as to how i can achieve my task please feel free to help.

the code below is an attempt to get just the value of q1 and doesn't work. there is is more than one row in the database but i don't think you can use WHERE in a SELECT statement?

```
<?php

session_start();

$connection = mysql_connect("mysql15.000webhost.com", "a4987634_quiz", "jimbo1")
or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("a4987634_quiz", $connection)
or die (mysql_error());

$username = $_SESSION["username"];
$password = $_SESSION["password"];

$sql = "Select * as total from users"

$result = mysql_query ($sql)

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$q1 = $row["q1"];

}

echo $q1 ;

?>
```

Comment: This reminds me of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109225/select-numbers-from-database-for-sum).

Answer (score 1):

`$q` is defined inside a cycle and shown outside it, where `$q` is already out of the scope. Make `print_r($q)` or `print_r($row)` inside the fetching cycle and you will see your results.

Comment: That wasn't exactly his issue here. By the way, scoping rules in PHP are pretty weak. The `$q1` variable isn't out of scope outside of the loop. In fact, once defined, it is available until the script ends.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "Select id, username, password, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, hscore, lscore from users WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "'";

if (!($result = mysql_query ($sql))) {
    echo "DB error: " . mysql_errno() . " => " . mysql_error() . "\n"; 
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found\n";
}
else if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 1) {
    echo "More than 1 row found for user $username\n";
}

$last_score = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $user = $row["username"];
    $last_score = $row["q1"] + $row["q2"] + $row["q3"] + $row["q4"] + $row["q5"];
    echo "$user => $last_score\n";
}
```

Comment: i don't understand what the $total has to do with it and what the variable name of the value q1 would be? thanks for reply though

Comment: thank you for your reply. when i say sum i mean i just want to add a bunch of numbers from the database. at the mo i am trying to get just one number which is where i'm failing. sorry if i'm mashing your brains.

Comment: i'm not sure where it s failing. when i change a few things i get different errors. at one point i got Resource id#9 which i believe is a good thing. when i the tried to put the $result through the while loop thats when the error came. so something to do with the while loop i think.

Comment: @JamesBriant you should really be more specific. You did not even say if you tried what I suggested. You might want to update your question. 1.) What specifically have you tried? 2.) What specific errors do you get from each of the things that you tried? 3.) Have you added error checking code?

Comment: when i tried you code i got this error whic won't mean much to you but it's on the same line as `$total = 0;`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/a4987634/public_html/result.php on line 69

Comment: i would tell you everything but i just can't remeber it. i'm sorry. if you feel the need to give please do.

Comment: @JamesBriant you should have said that a while ago. That is a parse error. You are missing a semi-colon after the SQL statement string.

Comment: i no longer have that error (can't believe i didn't see that) instead i get 0 0 0 . i do have more than one row in the database so that is the problem i think.

Comment: @JamesBriant If you want further help, please update the question at the top to show what your database looks like, what kind of output you want to see, and what output you currently get.

Comment: @JamesBriant I may or may not be available. Your best bet would be to edit your question at the top and add the specifics. Then I or anyone else can help you.

Comment: Is there any reason that you're posting under a different username? [Previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109225/select-numbers-from-database-for-sum).

Comment: @JamesBriant I just added a `WHERE` clause that will let you filter it based on the current user that is logged in. To answer the question you posed at the top, you can definitely use a `WHERE` clause in a `SELECT` statement. By the way, thank you for updating your question. It is much more detailed, and a lot easier to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: there are three rows in the database so this is what appeared on screen.   Tania => 25 james => 25 Dr Who => 13   appears to be right. from here i can say where to update the database (i think) thank you so much. i will put your name on the website to say thanks for your contribution. if you would like to have a look at the website please feel free. go to quiz.freeiz.com . have a go at the quiz but some you WILL get wrong becuase you will have no chance of getting it right. good luck though. james

Comment: is mysql_errno() an actual statement or is it a typo? thanks though. saved me some extra time.

Comment: @JamesBriant that is a real function call. The *errno* in it refers to the *error number*. The `mysql_errno() . " => " . mysql_error()` statement prints out the error number followed by the error description.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "Select field1, field2 from users";
$total= 0;
$result =mysql_fetch_object($resultmysql_query ($sql))
foreach ( $result as $value)
{
    $total = $value["field1"] + $value["field2"];
    echo "$total<br/>";
}
```